# Seems newer kernels cause CPU hard lookups

Tags: boot, kernel

Anyone experienced that after updating to newer kernel from 4.4.0-112 or 4.13.0-36? (ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

I can make it to boot sometimes if I use nomodeset parameter but 4.4 kernel feels like it's not using the integrated graphics (high compiz and xorg usage, overall jerkyness) Also I lose brightness control then...

```
NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu
```

When I boot with older kernel there are no issues...

Comment: Sorry you are having a problem . Try disabling the specter patch and / or file a bug report. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears it's a bug with intel-microcode: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920

It's being worked on but in the meantime I used a grub parameter

```
dis_ucode_ldr
```

to make it boot. As advised in the bug report, you can also revert to an earlier version of intel-microcode package.